# Equivalence of cross products Kunneth formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In Hatcher Theorem 3.19, he writes that the following cup product for $i+j=n$:
$$H^i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\mathbb{R}^j)\times H^j(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\mathbb{R}^i)\xrightarrow{\cup} H^n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}).$$
He then claims that it is equivalent to the cross product
$$H^i(I^i,\partial I^i)\times H^j(I^j,\partial I^j)\xrightarrow{\times} H^n(I^n,\partial I^n).$$
I can't seem to see how this is the case. I can short of see how the right hand side is induced by some sort of deformation retract, but I am confused about the rest of the geometry (how to shrink to $I^i$, for example), and what precisely needs to be done algebraically to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{
  \raise.8em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1}
  \lower.3em{\mathord{\diagup}}
  \raise.52em{\!\mathord{\nearrow}}
}}$

The pair $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\mathbb{R}^j)$ deformation retracts on its projection on $\mathbb{R}^i,$ the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb{R}^j$. This will make this pair into $(\mathbb{R}^i,\mathbb{R}^i-\{0\}).$ Expanding the "hole" $\{0\}$ and contracting $\mathbb{R}^i-\{0\}$ (as on the right) to a circle then gives the desired pair.

To convince oneself that the products are "the same", one can take a look at the diagram (I omit subspaces for simplicity):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^i(\mathbb{R}^n) \times H^j(\mathbb{R}^n) @>{\times}>>  H^n(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n) @>{\Delta^*}>> H^n(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
H^i(\mathbb{R}^i) \times H^j(\mathbb{R}^j) @>{\times}>> H^n(\mathbb{R}^i \times \mathbb{R}^j).
\end{CD}

The upper row is by definition what was given initially. The lower row is what has to be shown to be equivalent. The left vertical isomorphism here is by definition how we identify the corresponding groups. What needs to be done is we need to identify those target copies of $H^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ from both rows in a consistent way (to make this diagram commute when adding the isomorphism between these copies). But for the evident homeomorphism $s: \mathbb{R}^i \times \mathbb{R}^j \to \mathbb{R}^n$ the triangle commutes:

$\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n @<{\Delta}<< \mathbb{R}^n \\
@VVV \diaguparrow{s} \\
\mathbb{R}^i \times \mathbb{R}^j,
\end{CD}$

meaning that $s^*$ can be taken as the desired identification.

The passage to $(I^i,\partial I^i)$ can be done similarly, fixing the identifications on the left and making sure that the identification on the right is consistent with them.

Comment: I just realized that I don't quite understand what is happening when we are expanding the hole, even on the right hand side. I can see how we can end up with $(I^n,I^n-\{0\})$ from $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$ by deformation retract, but what is the continuous map $(I^n,I^n-\{0\})\rightarrow  (I^n,\partial I^n)$? At its core it is a map from $I^n\rightarrow I^n$ that respects the pair; it seems like we need to move all of $I^n-\{0\}$ to the boundary but I'm not sure how that can be continuous given $0$ in the middle.

Comment: @Vasting Good question. It's unclear indeed on the space level, but all you need is to know that $(I^n,\partial I^n) \rightarrow  (I^n,I^n-\{0\})$ gives an isomorphism on cohomology, which follows from the induced map of long exact sequences.

Comment: Just another quick question: what exacty is the map $H^n(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow H^n(\mathbb{R}^i\times\mathbb{R}^j)$? Intuitively it seems like the first copy of $\mathbb{R}^i$ should be included into the first copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and same for $\mathbb{R}^j$. But then it doesn't seem so clear that the triangle with $s$ commutes.

Comment: @Vasting In the triangle with spaces each $\mathbb{R}^n$ projects as in the first sentence of the answer. The cohomology then admittedly has to be mapped in the other direction; by maps $H^n(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow H^n(\mathbb{R}^i\times\mathbb{R}^j)$ I meant inverses of that.